# How to insert data into a MySQL table in MyQuery (Delphi)

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-7, mydac

I am doing mysql connection by establishing a user-registration application. I use Delphi 7. **Myquery** (MySQL Access Set) have a problem with adding user information.

```
MyQuery1.SQL.Clear;
MyQuery1.SQLInsert.Add('INSERT INTO uyeler (nick) VALUES ('+QuotedStr(DBEdit1.text)+')');
MyQuery1.SQLInsert.Add('INSERT INTO uyeler (mail) VALUES ('+QuotedStr(DBEdit2.text)+')');
MyQuery1.SQLInsert.Add('INSERT INTO uyeler (site) VALUES ('+QuotedStr(DBEdit3.text)+')');
MyQuery1.SQLInsert.Add('INSERT INTO uyeler (pass) VALUES ('+QuotedStr(DBEdit4.text)+')');
MyQuery1.CachedUpdates:=True;
MyQuery1.Open;
```

**Error message:** MyQuery1: No SQL statement provided.

**Note:** uyeler: members table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This message is raised because you are not filling the `SQL` property, instead you are using the `SQLInsert` which is a template  for query statements.

Some additional tips

1. You must use the `Execute` method, The `Open` method is for `SELECT` sentences.
2. use a single insert sentence like

   **INSERT INTO uyeler (nick,mail,site,pass) VALUES ('','','','')**
3. Try using parameters, instead of passing the string values directly, in this way you will avoid sql injection attacks and you will increase the performance.